# if we want to print the accounts of metamask in console log using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, metamask

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/sourcemaps/contentscript.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/sourcemaps/inpage.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
log.js:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
react-dom.development.js:24994 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: 
webpackHotDevClient.js:138 /home/abdul/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/src/scrypt.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:138
handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:143
push../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:210
[]

Answer (score -1):

please first you do

> `window.web3.currentProvider.enable()`

in web3.js file then remove enable and write

> (window.web3.currentProvider)

problem solved Congratulation.